# Assert list items without order

Tags: assertj

Seems very stupid, but I can't find good solution to this (I guess very basic) problem: I have an  list with elements that can not be checked by `equals`. Instead, I want to assert items state by their properties, and I want to do it ignoring item order.

`assertThat(list.get(xx))` doesn't fit, as it assumes knowing exact order.
`assertThat(list).containsInAnyOrder(xx, yyy, ...)` doesn't fit as it assumes being able to compare objects by `equals()`.
What I miss is something like `assertThat(list).containsInAnyOrder( Consumer<ObjectAssert<T>>...itemAssertions )`.
As a bonus, in my case I already have custom Assertion for my object type T, but I guess that would require really flexible API to use that for list items.

What do I miss?

Answer (score 1):

You can try [`usingRecursiveFieldByFieldElementComparator`](http://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/core-8/api/org/assertj/core/api/AbstractIterableAssert.html#usingRecursiveFieldByFieldElementComparator--) chained with [`containsExactlyInAnyOrder`](http://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/core-8/api/org/assertj/core/api/AbstractIterableAssert.html#containsExactlyInAnyOrder-ELEMENT...-) assertion.

Comment: Thank you. From the javadoc, `usingRecursiveFieldByFieldElementComparator` allows comparing fields by equals, but what I need is generic (ideally) or startsWith() and contains() comparison on certain fields.

Comment: [usingElementComparator](http://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/core-8/api/org/assertj/core/api/AbstractListAssert.html#usingElementComparator-java.util.Comparator-) should help but you have to write the comparator yourself